# php sqlite3 bindvalue crash

Tags: php, sqlite

`bindValue` crash my script :

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM player WHERE login=:login;');
echo "plop1";
$statement->bindValue(':login', $_POST["login"], SQLITE3_TEXT);
echo "plop2";
$result = $statement->execute();
echo "plop3";
```

plop1 is displayed but not plop2, I tryed to replace $_POST["login"] by a static value, but nothing changed, any idea ?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Please add some [PDO Error Checking](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just my bad, the table was not created because my query was wrong then `$db->prepare` return `false`. Now it works fine.